# Powershell Cmdlet Invocation Inconsistency

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-services

I am trying to call the specific cmdlet "Get-VpnConnection" from a PowerShell instance in a Windows service (.NET Framework 4.7).

I have been able to call this cmdlet successfully in a command-line project (also .NET Framework 4.7) and have been able to call other cmdlets from within this service (e.g. "Get-Date"). I have selected the highest account permissions for the package installer (LocalSystem).

Here is an excerpt of what I've tried:

```cs
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Get-VpnConnection");
                Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                WriteToFile(results.Count.ToString());
            }
```

When I run this from within the service, WriteToFile (a method I've created to write to a log text file in the program's base directory) will write "0" to the log whereas for "Get-Date" it would write "1". When I run this from within the main function of a command-line project, I get "1" as expected. No exceptions are thrown and no PowerShell Stream (Error or Verbose) contains anything. It's almost as if the cmdlet isn't being recognized as valid since providing a gibberish argument to AddCommand will produce an identical result.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: `Get-VpnConnection` enumerates vpn connections _per user_ - is the service running as the same user account for which it works as a console app?

Comment: Ahhh, I don't think so! I changed the package installation account to "User" and manually entered the credentials upon installation and everything worked after that! Can you please post your comment as a question so I can accept it as the answer? Also, do you know of any source for more in-depth PowerShell documentation aside from the Docs Microsoft has on their website? Thank you!